# Fallout Shelter crashing constantly after update

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-shelter, ios

My game keeps on crashing after an hour or five minutes. It is crashing sometimes when I'm getting attacked or have a fire, and has been happening since the last update.

Other than that it will just turn the screen black and goes to the home screen on my iPad.

Comment: After what was updated?

Answer (score -1):

Here are some things you can try. Delete and reinstall the app, free up storage space and make sure you don't have too many apps running in the background.